# How do I override, not replace, certain elements in an orm.xml file with an eclipselink-orm.xml file?

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

The [page documenting the `eclipselink-orm.xml` file](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/EclipseLink-ORM.XML) says, in part:

> This mapping file can be used in place of JPA's standard mapping file or **can be used to override a JPA mapping file**.

I'm interested in doing the latter, not the former.

Accordingly, I put the following in my `META-INF/persistence.xml` file:

```
<mapping-file>META-INF/my-orm.xml</mapping-file>
<mapping-file>META-INF/my-eclipselink-orm.xml</mapping-file>
```

They are picked up just fine.

Now, note that I do not want the contents of `my-eclipselink-orm.xml` to be a superset of the contents of `my-orm.xml`.  I just want to put the bare minimum of XML necessary in it to (semantically) add certain EclipseLink-specific features to a given mapping specified in `my-orm.xml`.

So now suppose I have a `<one-to-many>` mapping in `my-orm.xml` named `names`.  (Basic, basic stuff.)

Suppose now in `my-eclipselink-orm.xml` I'd like to semantically add the `<batch-fetch>` element to that mapping.

If I do this:

```
<entity class="the.entity.class.in.Question">
  <attributes>
    <one-to-many name="names">
      <batch-fetch size="10" type="JOIN"/>
    </one-to-many>
  </attributes>
</entity>
```

...then EclipseLink yells at me:

```
Conflicting XML elements [<one-to-many>] with the same name [names] were found. The first was found in the mapping file [file:/Users/ljnelson/Projects/foo/target/classes/META-INF/my-eclipselink-orm.xml] and the second in the mapping file [file:/Users/ljnelson/Projects/foo/target/classes/META-INF/my-real-orm.xml]. Named XML elements must be unique across the persistence unit.
```

So how do I override *only certain parts* of a "real" `orm.xml` with an `eclipselink-orm.xml`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This situation is covered in Example 6-4 of:
http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.6/jpa/extensions/schema.htm

Because the my-eclipselink-orm.xml is explicitly listed, it is treated like a JPA orm.xml file.  You will want to rename the file to eclipselink-orm.xml and remove the tag from the persistence.xml, so that your situation then matches Example 6-3.  The docs state it should merge mappings, but the examples aren't clear on this point.

Comment: Thank you, Chris; so to be clear the file must have the magic name of `META-INF/eclipselink-orm.xml`—i.e. naming it something else will always result in an exception? That was one of the takeaways I got from the referenced URL.  If it matters, in my case, as noted in my question, I do not have a `META-INF/orm.xml` but only other arbitrarily-named object-relational mapping files.

Comment: Another thing I found is odd: I am running this in a Maven unit test.  So in `target/classes` I have `META-INF/my-real-orm.xml` and (now) `META-INF/eclipselink-orm.xml`.  Of course my `persistence.xml`, which has nothing to do with my main resources' packaging, is in `test-classes/META-INF`.  EclipseLink searches for `eclipselink-orm.xml` in `test-classes/META-INF`, and, of course, does not find it. I would have thought it would have been sought on the classpath, not somehow "anchored" to the location of `persistence.xml`?

Comment: Files tied to a persistence unit are always relative to the persistence.xml.  My understanding from the docs is that META-INF/eclipselink-orm.xml relative to the persistence.xml is the default location for an Eclipselink-orm file, so that it does not need to be included in the persistence.xml if it is in that location.  Otherwise, if it is named in the persistence.xml file it is used as an orm.xml, disallowing overlaps.

Comment: Well, they're not, really—or at least they don't behave that way.  If I have a `test-classes/META-INF/persistence.xml` that specifically mentions `META-INF/my-orm.xml`, and _that_ file is in `classes` (not `test-classes`), everything works just fine. So I was curious why `eclipselink-orm.xml` is unique in behaving this way.

Comment: Anything explicitly listed in the persistence.xml is pulled from the classpath.  Anything that is left to be found by default, such as entities or orm.xml is relative to the persistence unit.

Comment: Thank you. The JPA Specification 2.1 section 8.2.1.6.2 reads rather categorically: "An `orm.xml` mapping file or other mapping file is loaded as a resource by the persistence provider." That I suppose was the source of my confusion; "as a resource" says to me it's located using a `ClassLoader`, no matter what.